# GHCi ignores type signature

Tags: haskell, ghci

```
Prelude> let myprint = putStrLn . show
Prelude> :t myprint
myprint :: () -> IO ()
```

OK, nothing too unusual here. Just GHCi type defaulting rules, I guess...

```
Prelude> let myprint = (putStrLn . show) :: Show x => x -> IO ()
Prelude> :t myprint
myprint :: () -> IO ()
```

What sorcery is this?? You're point-blank *ignoring* my type declaration?! O_O

Is there some way I can convince GHCi to do what I actually intended?

Comment: Wild guess: the dreaded monomorphism restriction.

Comment: @Jubobs That would be my guess as well - except that doesn't an explicit type signature disable that?

Comment: Are you using an old version of GHC? I'm on 7.8.3 and I get the type signature you'd *generally* expect (`Show a => a -> IO ()`), even without using a signature expression. Getting `() -> IO ()` seems like an actual problem with GHC.

Comment: @MasterMastic GHCi 7.4.2

Comment: The monomorphism restriction was turned off by default in GHCi 7.8.1 (*for GHCi only*), see https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.8.1/docs/html/users_guide/release-7-8-1.html#idp5920480.

Comment: @MvanGeest Is it because of the number of SO questions? ;-)

Comment: @MathematicalOrchid, that's pretty old. You should think about upgrading to 7.8, or I suppose you can wait another week or three for 7.10.

Comment: @dfeuer Really? I didn't think I installed it all that long ago... (Then again, I didn't think I've been using Haskell that long, and then I found a blog post I wrote **ten years ago**!...)

Comment: @MathematicalOrchid, 7.4.2 was released in June 2012. There have been some pretty nifty improvements since then.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

We can do the following, with monomorphism restriction on:

```
>let myprint :: Show x => x -> IO (); myprint = putStrLn . show
>:t myprint
myprint :: Show x => x -> IO ()
```

This is not the same as `let myprint = putStrLn . show :: Show x => x -> IO ()`. In the former case we have a binding with a type signature, in the latter case we a have a `let` binding with a type annotation inside the right hand side. Monomorphism checks top-level type signatures, but not local annotations.

Comment: I always recommend the `:set +m` flag, which lets you do multi-line input in GHCi.  It's really handy for instances like this, although I wish GHCi had smart indentation with multi-line input like IPython (project Jupyter is working on fixing this, though)

Answer (score 21):

Adding a type annotation to an *expression* as in

```
e :: type
```

makes the compiler check that `e` has that `type`, as well as use that `type` to drive type variables instantiation and instance selection. *However*, if the `type` is polymorphic it can still be instantiated later on. Consider e.g.

```
(id :: a -> a) "hello"
```

Above, `a` will be instantiated to `String`, despite my annotation. Further,

```
foo :: Int -> Int
foo = (id :: a -> a)
```

will make `a` to be instantiated to `Int` later on. The above `id` annotation does not give any information to GHC: it already knows that `id` has that type.
We could remove it without affecting the type checking at all. That is, the expressions `id` and `id :: a->a` are not only dynamically equivalent, but also statically such.

Similarly, the expressions

```
putStrLn . show
```

and

```
(putStrLn . show) :: Show x => x -> IO ()
```

are statically equivalent: we are just annotating the code with the type GHC can infer. In other words, we are not providing any information to GHC it does not already know.

After the annotation is type checked, GHC can then instantiate `x` further. The monomorphism restriction does that in your example. To prevent that, use an annotation for the *binding* you are introducing, not for the *expression*:

```
myprint :: Show x => x -> IO ()
myprint = (putStrLn . show)
```